# exception: geoNear command failed: errmsg: more than one 2d index

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, geometry, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to retrieve documents from a collection by distance. I've tried to use the `$geoNear` aggregation, but I either run into errors (using node.js and postman) or 0 records get returned.

**Sample Document:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cc37692fe9fd54b3cd136c9"),
    "category" : "art",
    "description" : "an eastbound description for The soda event.",
    "geometry" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            3.60178480057443, 
            6.46123057784917
        ]
    }
    "__v" : 0
}
.
.
```

**Model:**

```
const GeoSchema = new Schema({
  type: {
    type: String,
    default: "Point"
  },
  coordinates: {
    type: [Number],
    index: "2dsphere"
  }
}, { _id: false });

const EventSchema = new Schema({
  category: String,
  description: String,
  geometry: GeoSchema,
});
```

**Query**

```
db.events.aggregate([
   {
     $geoNear: {
        near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [3.60178480057443, 6.46123057784917] },
        distanceField: "dist",
        maxDistance: 90000,
        spherical: true
     }
   }
]);
```

Running the query above returns zero results, an empty array (on postman) and sometimes displays this error:

```
{
    "name": "MongoError",
    "errmsg": "exception: geoNear command failed: { ok: 0.0, errmsg: \"more than one 2d index, not sure which to run geoNear on\" }",
    "code": 16604,
    "ok": 0
}
```

When this error is displayed, I run the `db.events.dropIndex` function. I copied and pasted the examples used in the docs, and it worked fine. Please How do I make this $geoNear function work. I have been struggling with it for a whole day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Single collection cannot have more then one `2dsphere` index and You have created `2dsphere` index on more than one field by running following command.

```
db.getCollection('test').createIndex({ "loc": "2dsphere" })
```

So remove the one of the index and it will get work. You can check the list of indices using this

```
db.getCollection('test').getIndexes()
```

**Update:**

You can use [**`key`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/#pipe._S_geoNear) parameter to specify on which field do you want to make search with if your collection have multiple [**`$geoNear`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/#pipe._S_geoNear) indices